# Check field contains string including special character mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoDB and I would like to findOne document that contains the string. My string is "this is day one (day 1)" Here is my query:

```html
findOne({title : {$regex : ".*this is day one (day 1).*"}})
```

But it has special character like "()" so I though that regex recognised this a group. So what should I do to make this becomes a string.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\` to escape special characters

Change your query to

```
findOne({title : {$regex : ".*this is day one \(day 1\).*"}})
```

For dynamism, you can use this syntax to make your query

```
var titleSearch = "this is day one (day 1)";
findOne({title: {
                $regex: titleSearch,
                $options: 'i'
            });
```

Now, your `titleSearch` can be any string you want to search in your collection

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do we have anyway to make the sentence become a string? because my string is not fix. For example: it can include .?* or anything.